# no install folder after building VB.Net DAL2 Compiled Module

Tags: dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-7

I have a dnn 7 website set up locally for development through dnndev.me.  However I did not install the dnndev.me in the standard root folder c:\websites\dnndev.me\  it is in another location in my user documents.  But the dnn installation works fine.  So I added the *dotnetnuke project templates* and created a new project following the instructions on this page: 
http://www.chrishammond.com/blog/itemid/2616/using-the-new-module-development-templates-for-dot.aspx

When I build the module in debug and then release it says build successful and there are no errors, however there is no install folder and no installation files.

Dose some one have an idea of how I can trouble shoot this?

Thanks in advance.

### EDIT 1:

I have user both the C# and VB tempates as well as the Da2l and non-Dal2 templates.  Same problem with every template.

Also,

I tried updating the MsBuildCommunity to the current version, that did not solve the problem either.

And i tried reinstallin ghte msbuild from the project manager command line - i got an error and did not solve the problem.

### EDIT 2

So I am using version 2.5 of the templates. It appears that part of the build is working correctly because there are files generated and copied/created in the **dnndev.me\bin** folder and the **desktopmodlue\MODULENAME\obj\debug** folder.

I tried to run the build from the visual studio command prompt, here is the command prompt output from a newly created and un altered vb template with Dal2:

```
C:\websites\dnndev.me\DesktopModules\DNNModule1>msbuild DNNModule1.vbproj
Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 4.0.30319.33440
[Microsoft .NET Framework, version 4.0.30319.34003]
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

Build started 11/29/2013 11:34:58 PM.
Project "C:\websites\dnndev.me\DesktopModules\DNNModule1\DNNModule1.vbproj" on
node 1 (default targets).
GenerateTargetFrameworkMonikerAttribute:
Skipping target "GenerateTargetFrameworkMonikerAttribute" because all output fi
les are up-to-date with respect to the input files.
CoreCompile:
  C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Vbc.exe /noconfig /imports:Micr
  osoft.VisualBasic,System,System.Collections,System.Collections.Generic,System
  .Data,System.Linq,System.Diagnostics,System.Collections.Specialized,System.Co
  nfiguration,System.Text,System.Text.RegularExpressions,System.Web,System.Web.
  Caching,System.Web.SessionState,System.Web.Security,System.Web.Profile,System
  .Web.UI,System.Web.UI.WebControls,System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts,System.W
  eb.UI.HtmlControls /optioncompare:Binary /optionexplicit+ /optionstrict:custo
  m /nowarn:42016,41999,42017,42018,42019,42032,42036,42020,42021,42022 /option
  infer+ /nostdlib /rootnamespace:Christoc.Modules.DNNModule1 /sdkpath:"C:\Prog
  ram Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.0"
  /highentropyva- /doc:obj\Debug\DNNModule1.xml /define:"CONFIG=\"Debug\",DEBUG
  =-1,TRACE=-1,_MyType=\"Custom\",PLATFORM=\"AnyCPU\"" /reference:C:\websites\d
  nndev.me\bin\DotNetNuke.dll,C:\websites\dnndev.me\bin\DotNetNuke.WebUtility.d
  ll,"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFrame
  work\v4.0\System.Configuration.dll","C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assembl
  ies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.0\System.Core.dll","C:\Program Files
   (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.0\System.Dat
  a.DataSetExtensions.dll","C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microso
  ft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.0\System.Data.dll","C:\Program Files (x86)\Refe
  rence Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.0\System.dll","C:\Progr
  am Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.0\Sy
  stem.Drawing.dll","C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Fram
  ework\.NETFramework\v4.0\System.EnterpriseServices.dll","C:\Program Files (x8
  6)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.0\System.Web.dll
  ","C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramew
  ork\v4.0\System.Web.Extensions.dll","C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assembl
  ies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.0\System.Web.Mobile.dll","C:\Program
   Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.0\Syst
  em.Web.Services.dll","C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\F
  ramework\.NETFramework\v4.0\System.Xml.dll" /debug+ /debug:full /out:obj\Debu
  g\DNNModule1.dll /target:library Components\FeatureController.vb Components\I
  temController.vb Components\Item.vb Settings.ascx.designer.vb Settings.ascx.v
  b DNNModule1SettingsBase.vb Edit.ascx.designer.vb Edit.ascx.vb "My Project\As
  semblyInfo.vb" DNNModule1ModuleBase.vb View.ascx.designer.vb View.ascx.vb "C:
  \Users\Jordan\AppData\Local\Temp\.NETFramework,Version=v4.0.AssemblyAttribute
  s.vb"
vbc : warning BC40010: Possible problem detected while building assembly 'DNNMo
dule1': The version '00.00.01.*' specified for the 'file version' is not in the
 normal 'major.minor.build.revision' format [C:\websites\dnndev.me\DesktopModul
es\DNNModule1\DNNModule1.vbproj]
CopyFilesToOutputDirectory:
  Copying file from "obj\Debug\DNNModule1.dll" to "..\..\bin\DNNModule1.dll".
  DNNModule1 -> C:\websites\dnndev.me\bin\DNNModule1.dll
  Copying file from "obj\Debug\DNNModule1.pdb" to "..\..\bin\DNNModule1.pdb".
  Copying file from "obj\Debug\DNNModule1.xml" to "..\..\bin\DNNModule1.xml".
Done Building Project "C:\websites\dnndev.me\DesktopModules\DNNModule1\DNNModul
e1.vbproj" (default targets).


Build succeeded.

"C:\websites\dnndev.me\DesktopModules\DNNModule1\DNNModule1.vbproj" (default ta
rget) (1) ->
(CoreCompile target) ->
  vbc : warning BC40010: Possible problem detected while building assembly 'DNN
Module1': The version '00.00.01.*' specified for the 'file version' is not in t
he normal 'major.minor.build.revision' format [C:\websites\dnndev.me\DesktopMod
ules\DNNModule1\DNNModule1.vbproj]

    1 Warning(s)
    0 Error(s)

Time Elapsed 00:00:02.65

C:\websites\dnndev.me\DesktopModules\DNNModule1>
```

as for the  MSBuild Community Tasks. I have the following folder in the packages directory:
MSBuildTasks.1.4.0.61. If I go to menu Tools -> Library Package Manager -> Manage NuGet Packages for Solution, the MsBuildTasks is listed in the installed packages (v 1.4.0.61).

### EDIT 3

Okay, so i was thinking the same thing as chris in regards to the release vs debug setting.  So i manually triggered a realease build using the command promt /p:configuration=release.  THis caused a new error to appear:

```
C:\websites\dnndev.me\DesktopModules\DNNModule1>msbuild dnnmodule1.vbproj /p:Configuration=Release
Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 4.0.30319.33440
[Microsoft .NET Framework, version 4.0.30319.34003]
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

Build started 11/30/2013 12:06:27 AM.
Project "C:\websites\dnndev.me\DesktopModules\DNNModule1\dnnmodule1.vbproj" on node 1 (default targets).
GenerateTargetFrameworkMonikerAttribute:
Skipping target "GenerateTargetFrameworkMonikerAttribute" because all output files are up-to-date with respect to the input files.
CoreCompile:
Skipping target "CoreCompile" because all output files are up-to-date with respect to the input files.
CopyFilesToOutputDirectory:
  dnnmodule1 -> C:\websites\dnndev.me\bin\DNNModule1.dll
C:\websites\dnndev.me\DesktopModules\DNNModule1\BuildScripts\ModulePackage.targets(10,4): error MSB4062: The "MSBuild.Community.Tasks.XmlRead" task could not be loaded f
rom the assembly C:\websites\dnndev.me\DesktopModules\DNNModule1\BuildScripts\*Undefined*\packages\MSBuildTasks.1.4.0.61\tools\MSBuild.Community.Tasks.dll. Could not loa
d file or assembly 'file:///C:\websites\dnndev.me\DesktopModules\DNNModule1\BuildScripts\*Undefined*\packages\MSBuildTasks.1.4.0.61\tools\MSBuild.Community.Tasks.dll' or
 one of its dependencies. The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect. Confirm that the <UsingTask> declaration is correct, that the assembly and a
ll its dependencies are available, and that the task contains a public class that implements Microsoft.Build.Framework.ITask. [C:\websites\dnndev.me\DesktopModules\DNNMo
dule1\dnnmodule1.vbproj]
Done Building Project "C:\websites\dnndev.me\DesktopModules\DNNModule1\dnnmodule1.vbproj" (default targets) -- FAILED.


Build FAILED.
```

Here is the screen shot of where I switch to release from debug.  I must be missing something obvious.
[image]

Comment: My templates and development environment recommendations came from many years of trial and error, I would recommend not doing dnn stuff inside a user's folder in Windows.

Comment: @ChrisHammond  thanks for the reply and taking time to help.  I moved the site to c:\websites\dnndev.me and this did not fix the issue.  When I build in either debug or release, there is no install folder generated.  The dnndev.me site opens and work properly.  I am using VS 2012 professional.

Comment: Do you happen to know what version of my templates you are using? Can you confirm that MSBuild Community Tasks is still included in the project/packages/nuget?

Comment: @ChrisHammond , thanks for sticking with this, I updated my post to answer your questions and provide further details.

Comment: When you say "build in debug, then release", where are you switching it to RELEASE mode when you do so? Can you post a screenshot?

Comment: @ChrisHammond I was going the same direction.  I manually triggered  release build from the command prompt, see above.

Comment: @ChrisHammond, Okay, this is pretty embarrassing.  I was only switching the debug/release in the Project settings/properties.  Not in the top Build toolbar of the visual studio window.  Once I switched that I had to click the option to display hidden folders in the solution explorer, but it works.  Nothing wrong with the templates.  If you post your third comment as an answer I will accept it.  Thanks again and happy thanksgiving.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that you are switching to RELEASE mode in the Toolbar in VS, not just the project properties. If you don't see the build toolbar, I recommend you configure VS for C# mode instead of VB, then the dropdown becomes easy to access.